# Artist management company or artists management company?

Tags: grammatical-number, adjectives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nouns of plural form preceding another noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67701/nouns-of-plural-form-preceding-another-noun)

When talking about a company that guides professional career of artists (such as illustrators or photographers), helps them build their portfolio, promotes their services, would you refer to it as an "artist management" or "artist**s** management" company?

Google results suggest that both are used: 626,000 results for "artists management" vs. 3.3 million for "artist management".

What's the difference?

Comment: The "difference" is that idiomatically, when we use a noun in an "adjectival" role like this, we normally stick to the singular. For example, *car maintenance*, not ***cars** maintenance*.

Comment: ... *however*, this doesn't apply so strongly with all word-pairs. For example, although *building management* is the more common version, ***buildings** management* does occur about 20% of the time. Whereas with *fleet management*, the plural occurs far less than 1% of the time.

Comment: Possibly "building management" might be ambiguous: are you managing buildings or builders?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with "Artist Management" as the word is intended as a noun and not in any possessive form. For example, I would say, "MT Consulting" and not "MT's Consulting". Though both are grammatically correct, the latter implies a possession, which is not what you're going for.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me to be an example of one major usage difference between British and American English. American English prefers the singular nominal adjective while British English prefers the plural. The /-s/ suffix is not intended to indicate possession but plurality.

Comment: Do you have sources for your assertion that it's different for British and American English?

Comment: I read a lot (always have), studied English and American literature in graduate school, and have friends who are native speakers of British English and American English. Because we're all English as a foreign language (EFL) teachers, we talk about these kinds of things constantly. BrE speakers tell me what's normal in BrE and AmE speakers tell them what's normal in AmE. Caveat: Not all native speakers use the same conventions when speaking their native language. My assertion is a generalization, not something that's true 100% of the time.

Comment: 'Nominal adjectives' are adjectives used as nominals (eg as subjects), like 'the poor', 'the dead', 'the best [is yet to come]'. 'Artist/s' in 'Artist management company' (whether singular form or plural form) is an attributive **noun**, here one of two such premodifiers. // I can't agree with your generalisation. The usual state of attributive nouns is singular form (donkey sanctuary; football manager; exercise book ...) on both sides of the Atlantic. Exceptions occur (dogs home; systems analyst), usage again usually mirroring itself on both sides of the Atlantic